# Who are the Attributists Rambam speaks of

Tags: jewish-books, rambam, theology

in the 'Guide for the Perplexed' by Rabbi Moshe Maimonides, who are the 'attributists' he speaks of?  Are they other Jews with a different view, a different sect within Judaism, the Mohammedans, the Christians, or another group?
He speaks of them several times but this is an example:

"The Scriptures unquestionably ascribe to God Existence, Life, Power, Wisdom, Unity, Eternity, and Will. The Attributists regard these as properties distinct from, but co-existing with, the Essence of God. "

Comment: in the quran there are ayat(passages) referring to Allah(God) as having human attributes such body features. a small group among the sunnis took these as literal facts and were called attributists as they attributed corporeality  upon God https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8F_PW9P6dqlZm1XT1dXUXdKSXc ctrl f and type in attributists to bring you to the right place

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=fuv8J-g7EdAC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=attributists+muslims&source=bl&ots=P14kWXZ-T8&sig=eh_VOJ32Gleor7EhilKIslGYIHM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1rtzSzs_RAhXlh1QKHb_MCGcQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=attributists%20muslims&f=false

Comment: The quote in your question is not a passage written by Maimonides.